# При создании Edit in place некорректная робота mouseover

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, java, css

Ребят, помогите разобраться с двумя вопросами. Я сверстал с этого сайта Edit in place, но возникли две проблемы. Визуальное отображение проблемы в картинках:

[image]

Ссылки, откуда сверстан скрипт:

1. [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html)
2. [Jeditable – Edit In Place Plugin For jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

-

- Не работает mouseover (при редактировании телефонного номера не сохраняется текст а появляется информер Click to edit) Рисунок№3.
- Не знаю как в CSS прописать так что бы само поле редактирования телефона было таким как на Рисунке №1.

Вот сам листинг

```
    <!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mouseover").editable("http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/php/echo.php", {
        indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
        tooltip   : "to edit...",
        event     : "mouseover",
        style  : "inherit"
    });
    $("input").live("focus",function(){$(this).mask("+99 99 9999999")});
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
html { background: #f7f7f7; }
body { margin: 0px; font-size: 12px; line-height: 160%; font-family: "arial"; }


input { color:#416796; font:23px/1.4em Arial; padding:0; font-weight:bold; width: 370px; border:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center }

#wrap{
    margin: 10px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    text-align:center;
    color:#416796;
    font:23px/1.4em Arial;
 }
#inner {
    width: 620px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
.variant {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 1px auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 7px;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#text{
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 10px;
    color:#4e4e4e;

}
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; }
.container { background:#e4e7f1;
    padding: 0px 14px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

.variant span { background: url("assets/icons.png") 2px -173px no-repeat; display: block; width: 25px; height: 15px; float: left; }
.variant:hover span { background: url("assets/icons.png") 2px -205px no-repeat; }
.variant:hover { background: #e4e7f1; cursor: pointer; }
.checked, .checked:hover { background: #9eafc3; color: #FFF; }
.checked span, .checked:hover span { background: url("assets/icons.png") 2px -189px no-repeat; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
   <br><br><br><br>
    <div id="text"><b>Please, check if your phone number is correct</span></font></font></b></div>
     <hr size="1" width="100%">  
      <div class="container grid">
       <div id="wrap">
        <b title="to edit..." class="mouseover" style="display: inline">+00 00 0000000</b>
        <div id="text"> If it is wrong, please enter your phone number and then submit</div>
       </div>
      </div> 
     <hr size="1" width="100%"> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы номер телефона был как на рисунке надо подключить [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). Возможно из-за этого же и проблема с сохранением.

Ну а далее в скрипте

В стили допишите:

```
input { color:#416796; font:23px/1.4em Arial; padding:0; font-weight:bold; width: 370px; border:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center }
```

JS скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mouseover").editable("http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/php/echo.php", {
        indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
        tooltip   : "to edit...",
        event     : "mouseover",
        style  : "inherit"
    });
    $("input").live("focus",function(){$(this).mask("+99 99 9999999")});
});
</script>
```

maskedinput естественно должен быть подключен, т.е. в head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jeditable.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

C версией jQuery 1.3.2 работает отлично, попробовал 1.4.2, maskedinput глючит

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: DemoS, скрипт перестал работать =( причина не известна

Comment: Второй раз `$(".mouseover").editable("h...` не нужно